# What is the rationale behind the pthread_cond_broadcast?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, condition-variable

I am trying to understand practical use-cases of `pthread_cond_broadcast` method.

I have found two answers so far:

1. Different threads might wait on different conditions therefore you need to wake all of them up to see which one can proceed.
2. If there are multiple resources to be consumed, you can wake multiple of them to proceed.

The #1 makes sense, however, #2 is confusing. I have found following code that demonstrates this case. My question is that, since when condition variable is awaken, it will acquire the mutex and other threads have to sleep again. Then, what is the point of awakening all of them? Is pthread keeping the signal till all of the threads have a chance to acquire mutex at least once? It seems to me that there is no point  since only one of them can acquire the mutex.

I must be missing a point and hoping that someone can explain it to me.

Thank you very much!

reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/sync-27/index.html

```cpp
pthread_mutex_t rsrc_lock;
pthread_cond_t rsrc_add;
unsigned int resources;

get_resources(int amount)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&rsrc_lock);
    while (resources < amount) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&rsrc_add, &rsrc_lock);
    }
    resources -= amount;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&rsrc_lock);
}

add_resources(int amount)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&rsrc_lock);
    resources += amount;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&rsrc_add);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&rsrc_lock);
}
```

Comment: The thread could acquire the mutex just long enough to grab the resource it was waiting for, then release the mutex before starting some long task. It is true that the other threads would have to wait briefly right after being awakened and before they can in turn acquire the same mutex - but that doesn't mean they have to go back to waiting on the condition variable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is what i was wondering, thank you! Do you have any doc that states this?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have written a sample code and checked it. You are right, it unlocks all of them. They do not go back to sleep on checking condition variable. You can post an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: It worked even if threads hold mutex for 10s, so it is like each thread will get its fair chance to check mutex once.

Comment: Well, [the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032r/index.html#sync-44265): "This function blocks until the condition is signaled. It atomically releases the associated mutex lock before blocking, and atomically acquires it again before returning." It doesn't say "blocks until the condition is signaled and the mutex is free, simultaneously". It just acquires the mutex as if by calling `pthread_mutex_lock` - that'll wait as long as necessary.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that makes sense. All threads are going to be scheduled to run, acquire mutex and check the resource condition. If there are multiple resources, then they will proceed one after the another one. Thank you again for the discussion, it was very helpful!